# unzip .tar.gz file in terminal

Tags: command-line, directory, tar, gzip

How do I unzip a .tar.gz file in the terminal?  I'm not able to do so in GUI, because I want to extract it to a /usr directory, and will need the sudo command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gzip -d this_is_the_file.tar.gz
tar -xvf this_is_the_file.tar
```

These can be combined, but it's probably better to start out with the two commands independently.

- `gzip -d` ⇢ Decompress
- `tar -xvf` ⇢ Extract, Verbose, File

This should do what you need.